# Are MacOS usernames case sensitive or insensitive?

Tags: macos

I have a simple question:

Are MacOS usernames case sensitive or insensitive? I mean, can I have 2 users "test" and "Test" in MacOS?

from a simple check that I have made I noticed its the same as in windows which means that you can't have 2 users "test" and "Test".

But, someone told me that it's might be different in some kind of version of MacOS and i couldn't find anything about it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The user lookup system on macOS is (mostly) case-insensitive, so you can't have different accounts that differ only by capitalization.

Well, actually it is technically possible, but it's a *really* bad idea, and the OS tries to keep you from doing it. I saw a Mac that had a different-capitalization name conflict once (one was a local account, the other was in a network domain that the Mac was joined to), and it caused all sorts of weird problems.

Answer (score 0):

By default, it's case-insensitive so you can't have 2 users ("Test" and "test").

However you can specify if your partition is [case-sensitive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/222967):

> You have to specifically erase a partition and select case-sensitive for a partition to be case-sensitive.

Usually, case-sensitive systems are only for specific reasons.

**To answer the other question:**

Even if you specify your MacOS install as case-sensitive you can't really have those 2 users because (*source from the answer below*) the user lookup system on macOS is (mostly) case insensitive, so even with a case-insensitive volume you can't have both "test" and "Test".

I recommend you [to not mess up with](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/8028) **unless**:

> a) Know what you're doing
>
> b) You absolutely have to.
>
> There are several programs (Norton Antivirus comes to mind) that won't work properly on a case-sensitive file system.

TL;DR: **No, you can't.** Even if you specify your system as case-sensitive it's not a good idea.

Comment: Using a case-sensitive volume will allow the directories "/Users/Test" and "/Users/test" to both exist *but* that doesn't mean you can have accounts by both of those names. The user lookup system on macOS is (mostly) case insensitive, so even with a case-insensitive volume you can't have both "test" and "Test".

Comment: @GordonDavisson I see, added that to my answer. Good point though, thanks!